# content types of insertion

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a CSV file that contains a lot of integer values. Is it better to insert these individual values in bulk as in a full transaction or should I be inserting the CSV file itself into the MySQL?

Comment: What are you going to do with the data after it is in the database?  That would probably help give some perspective that would help with answers.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the individual values in bulk. In other words, each row of the csv file should become a row in the database with the same number of columns.

Using Notepad++ you can use a regex find and replace to easily convert your CSV into a very large insert statement. Replace `\r\n` with `'),('` and  `,` with `','`. Tidy up the first and last line of the file, then add the actual insert statement to the front. `insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values .....`